# Cannot send information to dialog box in Outlook add-in

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I cannot send information to my dialogbox in my Outlook add-in. Here is the Javascript code in the parent:

```
 var url2 = window.location.origin+'/dialogbox.html'
 var dialog
 Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url2, {height: 50, width: 50},
           function (asyncResult) {
               dialog.messageChild('hello from the parent', {targetOrigin: "*" })     
           });
```

Which completes successfully to the `messageChild` command.

The Javascript in the child dialog box is:

```
Office.onReady().then(function() {
         Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync(
             Office.EventType.DialogParentMessageReceived,
             onMessageFromParent);
         });
        
function onMessageFromParent(arg){
     console.log(arg.message)
     }
```

However, the message 'hello from the parent' is not printed in the console.

Instead I get the following in the console twice:

```
Tracking Prevention blocked access to storage for https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js. [https://localhost:3000/commands.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.02$en-US$$$$0]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass the message to the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the Office dialog API to open a dialog box, a Dialog object is returned. You will need to set the dialog object from the asyncResult on your local dialog variable. More information about messageChild can be found in the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-messagechild-from-the-host-page).

```
var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html',
    function (asyncResult) {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.messageChild(...);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now get the error `TypeError: Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync is not a function at c:\Users\User\Email domain checker\src\dialogbox\dialogbox.js:3:27`. Have I not loaded the dialog API correctly?                               I also realised I hadn't referenced the dialogbox.js script in the webpack.config.js. script Is there some documentation on what needs to be referenced where? It isn't entirely clear to me what webpack.config.js file and some other files that the Yeoman Generator produced do and what I need to do to make the add-in work. Thank you

Comment: You can determine if your version of Outlook and if you have a supported requirement set using this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/dialog-api-requirement-sets. There is documentation about how to use the dialog API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins and sample add-ins here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#samples